# Error executing query on MongoDB using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to execute a simple insert query using PHP as the scripting language.
However , I am getting the following error instance while executing it.

```
array(2) { ["ok"]=> float(0) ["errmsg"]=> string(12) "unauthorized" }
```

I wrote the following code on my local machine and it worked fine :

```
$mongoClient = new MongoClient('localhost');
$mongoDB=$mongoClient->test_db;
$mql='db.products.insert( { item: "card", qty: 15 } );';
$data=$mongoDB->execute($mql);
var_dump($data);die;
```

However , when I run the same code on my dev server using the following code segment while creating the MongoClient object , I am getting the above stated error.

```
$mongoClient=new MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@dbServer:port/test_db');
$mongoDB=$mongoClient->test_db;
$mql='db.products.insert( { item: "card", qty: 15 } );';
$data=$mongoDB->execute($mql);
var_dump($data);die;
```

On the same DB server , I am able to execute the same query through shell. 
From the code I can see that I am trying to select the database twice but then I'm left fully confused if that can be the error and how will I eliminate that. 
If that's not the error , I'm too clueless to find it.

I am using RackSpace cloud servers and ObjectRocket (by Rackspace) for MongoDB instances to be specific but then it should not be anyhow related to the problem. Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not using PHP but evaled JS, you are using PHP to call to MongoDBs eval comand. Later versions of MongoDB require the user running eval to have complete and uncontrolled access (super admin) to the database.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/

> Changed in version 2.4: You must have full admin access to run.

What you should be doing is NOT using eval:

```
$mongoDB->products->insert(['item' => 'card', 'qty' => 15])
```

Like so

Also `mql`? It is not mongo query language you are writing, it is JavaScript.

Comment: thanks !
and mql was the variable picked up in hurry... ignore that  ;)

Comment: @ArpitGaur ah ok :) a lot of people mistake it